# interpreting webkit layout tests

Tags: webkit

I have a task of breaking down webkit layout test results by passed/failed/skiped/crashed tests
I'm trying to comprehend what kind of "categories" to expect on the output.
I understood the NEW tests and the FAILED tests are shown in the results.txt but what about the rest?

These are the current categories I discovered so far

```
stderr
incorrect layout
succeeded
timed out
```

what else should I consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the failure types in [test_failures.py](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Tools/Scripts/webkitpy/layout_tests/models/test_failures.py#L220). They are

- Test crashed
- Test timed out
- Expected output (whether image, audio, or text) is missing
- Expected text output did not match actual output
- Expected image hash (checksum) output did not match actual output
- Expected image data (actual pixels) output did not match actual output
- Expected image *and* text output did not match actual output
- Expected audio output did not match actual output